# Tests do not run using Spring WebFlux & Reactive MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning Spring Boot, and am working with Spring WebFlux, and reactive Mongo DB.  My controllers are working fine, but my tests are failing on null pointer exception.

My build.gradle is:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'guru.springframework'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'

    //testCompile group: 'de.flapdoodle.embed', name: 'de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo', version: '3.0.0'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

My Controller is:

package guru.springframework.spring5webfluxrest.controllers;

```
import guru.springframework.spring5webfluxrest.domain.Category;
import guru.springframework.spring5webfluxrest.repositories.CategoryRepository;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.concurrent.Flow;

@RestController
public class CategoryController {
    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    public CategoryController(CategoryRepository categoryRepository) {
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/categories")
    public Flux<Category> list(){
        return categoryRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/categories/{id}")
    public Mono<Category> getById(@PathVariable String id){
        return categoryRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping("/api/v1/categories")
    public Mono<Void> create(@RequestBody Publisher<Category> categoryStream){
        return categoryRepository.saveAll(categoryStream).then();
    }

    @PutMapping("/api/v1/categories/{id}")
    public Mono<Category> update (@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Category category){
        category.setId(id);
        return categoryRepository.save(category);
    }

    @PatchMapping("/api/v1/categories/{id}")
    public Mono<Category> patch(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Category category){
        Category foundCategory = categoryRepository.findById(id).block();

        if(category.getDescription() != foundCategory.getDescription()){
            foundCategory.setDescription(category.getDescription());
            return categoryRepository.save(foundCategory);
        }
        return Mono.just(foundCategory);
    }


}
```

My test is:

```
package guru.springframework.spring5webfluxrest.controllers;

import guru.springframework.spring5webfluxrest.domain.Category;
import guru.springframework.spring5webfluxrest.repositories.CategoryRepository;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
//import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.BDDMockito;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.never;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;


public class CategoryControllerTest {
    
    WebTestClient webTestClient;
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    CategoryController categoryController;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        categoryRepository = Mockito.mock(CategoryRepository.class);
        categoryController = new CategoryController(categoryRepository);
        webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToController(categoryController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void list() {
        given(categoryRepository.findAll())
                .willReturn(Flux.just(Category.builder().description("Cat1").build(),
                        Category.builder().description("Cat2").build()));

        webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/api/v1/categories/")
                .exchange()
                .expectBodyList(Category.class)
                .hasSize(2);
    }

    @Test
    public void getById() {
        given(categoryRepository.findById("someid"))
                .willReturn(Mono.just(Category.builder().description("Cat").build()));

        webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/api/v1/categories/someid")
                .exchange()
                .expectBody(Category.class);

    }

    @Test
    public void create() {
        given(categoryRepository.saveAll(any(Publisher.class)))
                .willReturn(Flux.just(Category.builder().description("descrp").build()));

        Mono<Category> catToSaveMono = Mono.just(Category.builder().description("Some Cat").build());

        webTestClient.post()
                .uri("/api/v1/categories")
                .body(catToSaveMono, Category.class)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isCreated();
    }

    @Test
    public void update() {
        given(categoryRepository.save(any(Category.class)))
                .willReturn(Mono.just(Category.builder().build()));

        Mono<Category> catToUpdateMono = Mono.just(Category.builder().description("Some Cat").build());

        webTestClient.put()
                .uri("/api/v1/categories/asdfjkl")
                .body(catToUpdateMono, Category.class)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPatchNoChanges() {
        given(categoryRepository.findById(anyString()))
                .willReturn(Mono.just(Category.builder().build()));

        given(categoryRepository.save(any(Category.class)))
                .willReturn(Mono.just(Category.builder().build()));

        Mono<Category> catToUpdateMono = Mono.just(Category.builder().build());

        webTestClient.patch()
                .uri("/api/v1/categories/asdfasdf")
                .body(catToUpdateMono, Category.class)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk();

        verify(categoryRepository, never()).save(any());
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the exception stacktrace

Comment: This is what comes up
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [guru.springframework.spring5webfluxrest.controllers.CategoryControllerTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)
* Try:Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':test'.

Comment: Can you update the question post with the whole stacktrace

Comment: It was too many lines unfortunate,  My Git is here if you want to try to run it, https://github.com/DntMesArnd/spring5-webflux-rest.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test is annotated with the JUnit4's `@Test` annotation but you are trying to run it with JUnit5. JUnit5 cannot see it.

Uncomment the `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` import and remove  `import org.junit.Test` (CategoryControllerTest).

Remove `implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'` from the `build.gradle` as well.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I am using junit4 for the test.   I did try to remove the junit:junit:4.12, but it will not allow me to use the @Befoer annotation for the test.

Comment: If you want to use JUnit4, remove useJUnitPlatform() from the build.gradle

Comment: I removed it and am seeing the following error

Comment: > Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:

Comment: Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [guru.springframework.spring5webfluxrest.controllers.CategoryControllerTest.list](filter.includeTestsMatching)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 497ms
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date

Comment: This course is a couple years old, and said to use the embedded reactive MongoDB.  This seems to no longer be an option on Spring \Boot.  Any chance that has something to do with it?

Comment: It has nothing to do with MongoDB, it's still the same problem: "No tests found for given includes". You need to get the JUnit config right .

Comment: Thanks I'll play with it

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I started from scratch using JUnit 5 from Spring Initializer.  It's working now. Much Appreciated!